# Subir una imagen con medidas y formato especifico desde formulario

Tags: php, html, css

Agradezco su ayuda, nesecito subir una imagen mediante formulario pero con medias especificas y formato especifico, las medidas son 3000px X 3000px y en formato jpg, cuando el usuario suba una imagen con otras medidas y otro formato nesecito que salga el siguiente mesaje de error,

"Error! La imagen debe ser de 3000 px X 3000 px Cuadrado en Formato JPG Imagen de Alta Calidad, Suba la Imagen con estas especificaciones"

Soy Nuevo y Estoy Aprendiendo haciendo este proyecto Personal..

Esto es lo que tengo

```
<div class="container__group">
              <input type="text" id="file__txt" class="file__txt" readonly placeholder="Buscar">
              <div class="container__file">
                <span>Subir imagen</span>
                <input type="file" name="portadaimg" id="portadaimg" class="file" accept="image/jpeg" required>
              </div>
            </div>
```

Comment: uq pasa si por casualidad la imagen tiene 3001px o 2999px?

Comment: que has intentado hacer para validar esya informacion; la verdad que el codigo html que adjuntaste no demuestra que has investigado o intentado.

Comment: que tiene que ver php con lo que pides; me parece que si esto esta asociado a un codigo html deberia de hacerce con javascript.

Comment: ArcanisGK507 Me gustaria tener su experiencia, como indique soy nuevo estoy aprendiendo, buscare la opcion con java,

Comment: Lo que pasa es que el sitio no es un foro...

Comment: Hola, Bienvenid@ al Sitio, veo que eres nuev@ te recomendaria hacer el [tour] para que conoscas mejor el sitio, He mirado tu post y te comento lo siguiente:, Puedes leer este Articulo [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida, Puedes leer este Articulo [mre], También es importante que sepas que preguntas son mal vistas [help/dont-ask].

Answer (score 2):

Por lo que veo no es algo muy complicado, también veo que estás en una etiqueta de php, generalmente este tipo de comprobaciones se hacen mediante js, y en el backend con php puedes rectificar que sea ese formato.

```js
var tamano = false;

function validar() {
  var o = document.getElementById('portadaimg');
  var foto = o.files[0];
  var c = 0;

  if (o.files.length == 0 || !(/\.(jpg)$/i).test(foto.name)) {
    alert('Ingrese una imagen con alguno de los siguientes formatos: .jpeg/.jpg.');
    return false;
  }

  // Si el tamaño de la imagen fue validado
  if (tamano) {
    return true;
  }

  var img = new Image();
  img.onload = function dimension() {
    if (this.width.toFixed(0) != 3000 && this.height.toFixed(0) != 3000) {
      alert('Las medidas deben ser: 3000 x 3000');
    } else {
      alert('Imagen correcta :)');
      tamano = true;

      var form = document.getElementById('formulario');

      form.submit();
    }
  };
  img.src = URL.createObjectURL(foto);

  return false;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form action="" method="POST" id="formulario" onSubmit="return validar()">
  <div class="container__group">
    <div class="container__file">
      <span>Subir imagen</span>
      <input type="file" accept="image/jpeg" name="portadaimg" id="portadaimg" class="file" accept="image/jpeg" required>
    </div>
    <br>
    <input type="submit" value="Cargar" name="crear">
  </div>
  </form>
```

Pero este código te servirá para tu front-end.
Espero haberte ayudado.

Saludos.

PD: **PROCURA HACER TU CÓDIGO JS EN UN DOCUMENTO DIFERENTE COMO RECOMENDACIÓN**

Answer (score 1):

Es inusual que quieras validar esa resolución exacta... El caso es que si quieres validarlo del lado del cliente podrías hacerlo usando `FileReader` api en Javascript:

```js
(function() {
  var input = document.querySelector('input[type=file]');
  var container = document.querySelector('.img');
  var RES_WIDTH = 3000;
  var RES_HEIGHT = 3000;

  input.addEventListener('change', function(e) {
    var file = e.target.files[0];
    var img = new Image();
    var reader = new FileReader();

    reader.onload = function() {
      img.onload = function() {
        container.innerHTML = '';

        if (img.width !== RES_WIDTH && img.height !== RES_HEIGHT) {
          input.value = '';
          var msg = "Error! La imagen debe ser de 3000 px X 3000 px Cuadrado en Formato JPG Imagen de Alta Calidad, Suba la Imagen con estas especificaciones";
          alert(msg);
        } else {
          var span = document.createElement('span');
          span.textContent = img.width + 'x' + img.height; 
          container.appendChild(img);
          container.appendChild(span);
        }
      };

      img.src = reader.result;
    };

    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
  });
})();
```

```css
.container__group {
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
}

img {
  width: 130px;
  height: auto;
  display: block;
}

.img span {
  font-family: monospace;
}
```

```html
<div class="container__group">
  <div class="container__file">
    <span>Subir imagen</span>
    <input
      type="file"
      name="portadaimg"
      id="portadaimg"
      class="file"
      accept="image/jpeg"
      required
    />
  </div>
</div>

<div class="img"></div>
```